# Getting an image from an XMLHttpRequest and displaying it

Tags: image, html, canvas, jpeg, data-uri

I got this web service that gives me a (jpeg) image. What I want is take this image, convert it into a Data URI and display it on an HTML5 canvas, like that:

```
obj = {};

    obj.xmlDoc = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    obj.xmlDoc.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/mjpegcgi.cgi?x=1",false, "admin", "admin");
    obj.xmlDoc.send("");

    obj.oCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas-processor");
    obj.canvasProcessorContext = obj.oCanvas.getContext("2d");

    obj.base64Img = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( obj.xmlDoc.responseText )));

    obj.img = new Image();
    obj.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + obj.base64Img;
    obj.img.src = obj.src
    obj.canvasProcessorContext.drawImage(obj.img,0,0);
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code doesn't work; the image is not painted on the canvas at all (plus it seems to have width and height = 0, could it be not decoded correctly? I get no exceptions). img.src looks like `data:image/jpeg;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklG....`

**Resolved**: turns out I should have overridden the mime type with:

```
req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

and set the response type with:

```
req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

(see [this](http://jsperf.com/encoding-xhr-image-data/14). You should make an asynchronous request if you change the response type, too).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an img element (which is hidden)
Then you do exactly what you have done except that you listen to your onload event on your img element.
When this event is launched you are able to get the width and height of your pictures so you can set your canvas to the same size.

The you can draw your image as you did in last line.

Comment: I tought images with a data URI source were immediately ready, but even if with the onload event it won't work (onerror is fired instead). I resolved the problem anyway, see my last edit.